# Issue related to Error inflating class android.widget.TimePicker

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I have problem while i am debugging my application, when i click the button with timePicker this
Error occurs

**'Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.TimePicker'**

Can somebody help me with this issue 
That is my XML code :

```
<Label Text="Godzina" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Grid.Row="8"  TextColor="Black" Font="Bold,14"></Label>
                    <TimePicker x:Name="StartHour"
                Format="T" Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  BindingContext="{Binding StartHour}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    </TimePicker>
                    <TimePicker x:Name="EndHour"
                Format="T" Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BindingContext="{Binding EndHour}"  Grid.Column="3"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    </TimePicker>
            <Label Text="Miejsce spotkania" Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  TextColor="Black" Font="Bold,14"></Label>
                    <controls:CustomEntry x:Name="Place" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Text="{Binding Place}" Grid.Row="11"></controls:CustomEntry>
            <Label Text="Przypomnienie" Grid.Row="12" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  TextColor="Black" Font="Bold,14"></Label>
                    <TimePicker x:Name="Reminder"
                Format="T" Grid.Row="13" BindingContext="{Binding Reminder}" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    </TimePicker>
                    <Button x:Name="MakeMeeting"  Command="{Binding CreateCommand}" Text="Stworz spotkanie" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"   BackgroundColor="#034ad7" BorderRadius="14" TextColor="FloralWhite" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="14"></Button>
```

Comment: Can you please share the rest of your XML code? What is on Line 20 of that XML file? Also share your C# code for this page. Also share you styles.xml file. There could be a lot of reason for this error

Comment: I test the xml code you provide, no error. Could you provide the more details for us to reproduce? What would happen when you click the button with timePicker?

Comment: The reason I've found is that the TimePicker does not work with ScrollView, this is a bug, some ideas how to resolve it ?

Comment: i get this exception only on android 6 version. Do you still experience this crash?

Comment: i see this issue in my app's telemetry. it looks like it is a device-specific problem... Samsung devices with Android version 5 and 6...

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I've found is that the TimePicker does not work with ScrollView, this is a bug, some ideas how to resolve it ?

Based on my test, we could use TimePicker work with ScorellView. I test with your layout. Due to I do not have your viewmodel, I only show the gif of layout.

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Godzina" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Grid.Row="8"  TextColor="Black" Font="Bold,14"></Label>
            <TimePicker x:Name="StartHour"
            Format="T" Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  BindingContext="{Binding StartHour}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            </TimePicker>
            <TimePicker x:Name="EndHour"
            Format="T" Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BindingContext="{Binding EndHour}"  Grid.Column="3"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            </TimePicker>
            <Label Text="Miejsce spotkania" Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  TextColor="Black" Font="Bold,14"></Label>
            <!--<controls:CustomEntry x:Name="Place" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Text="{Binding Place}" Grid.Row="11"></controls:CustomEntry>-->
            <Label Text="Przypomnienie" Grid.Row="12" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  TextColor="Black" Font="Bold,14"></Label>
            <TimePicker x:Name="Reminder"
            Format="T" Grid.Row="13" BindingContext="{Binding Reminder}" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            </TimePicker>
            <Button x:Name="MakeMeeting"  Command="{Binding CreateCommand}" Text="Stworz spotkanie" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"   BackgroundColor="#034ad7" BorderRadius="14" TextColor="FloralWhite" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="14"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

You could download from the ScorellView_TimePciker folder of GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

**Updated:**

I test the same code in my previous reply. It could run well on `Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991265`. You could check the source code from `ScorellView_TimePicker_4.4.0.991265` folder on GitHub.

https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/ScorellView_TimePicker_4.4.0.991265/XamarinTest

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9103#issuecomment-571275875 Thanks

Comment: I test the code on GitHub. https://github.com/rozek1szymon/InvalidTimePicker.git You could check the image. https://imgur.com/AAPSSOY It could use TimePicker on ScorellView on Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991265 with no error. I have update my reply, you could check it.

Comment: I do not have the same devices on github like Galaxy S5, but on my device, it works well.